Why Dattatreya is known as Guru of the Yogis?
I read on the website of a Sadhu from Juna Akhara that Dattatreya is the Guru of the Yogis even before Shankara. Is there any Vedic or Puranic narrative that supports this claim? Who is Dattatreya? What is his connection with Yogi or Sadhus? Why do all sadhus think he is the origin of the Sannyasi Sanghas?

Markandeya purana [Canto XVII] says that the Prajāpati Atri begot three sons by his wife Anasūyā, namely, Soma, Dattātreya, and Durvāsas, who were incarnations of portions of Brahmā, Viṣṇu and Śiva respectively [Slokas: 86-103].
Dattātreya(दत्तात्रेय), as a yogi, appears to adopt unorthodox Vāmāchāra Mārgam (वामाचार मार्गम्/வாமாச்சார மார்க்கம்/Left-hand path) expressed in the following slokas [107-115]:
दत्तात्रेयो$पि विषयान्योगस्थो ददृशे हरिः। 
दुर्वासाः पितर त्यक्त्वा मातर चोत्तम व्रतम्‌॥ १०७॥ 
उन्मत्ताख्य समाश्रित्य परिबभ्राम मेदिनीम्‌ 


Dattatreya also, being Visnu, enjoyed objects of sense while engaged
in profound meditation Durvasas, deeming his father and mother to be
the chiefest object of devotion, assuming the form known as
'frantic,’ roamed about the earth.

मुनिपुत्रवृतों योगी दत्तात्रेयोऽप्यसङ्गित्ताम्‌॥ १० ८॥
अभीप्समानः सरसि निममज्ज चिर विभुः। 
तथापि त महात्मानमतीव प्रियदर्शनम्‌॥ १० ९॥
तत्यजुर्न कुमारास्ते सरसस्तीरसश्रयाः


Surrounded by the sons of Munis, the lordly yogi Dattatreya also,
desirous of obtaining exemption from all attachments, long Immersed
himself in a lake Nevertheless those youths, resorting to the bank of
the lake, did not forsake him, who was magnanimous and exceedingly
benign.

दिव्ये वर्षशते पूर्णे यदा तेन त्यजन्ति तम्‌॥ ११०॥ 
तत्प्रीत्या सरसस्तीर सर्वे मुनिकुमारकाः।
ततो दिव्याम्बरधरा सुरूपा सुनितम्बिनीम्‌॥ १११॥
नारीमादाय कल्याणीमुत्ततार जलान्मुनिः। 
स्त्रोसन्निकर्षिण होते परित्यक्ष्यन्ति मामिति॥ ११२॥
मुनिपुत्रास्ततो योगे स्थास्यामीति विचिन्तयन्‌


When after a hundied heavenly years were ended, all those youthful
Munts, through affection for him, still forsook not the bank of the
lake, the Muni, taking his noble wife clothed ın heavenly raiment,
beautiful and plump ın form, arose trom the water, thinking, If these
sons or Munis shall forsake me because of the presence of a woman,
then I will remain free from all attachments.

तथापि ते मुनिसुता न त्यजन्ति यदा मुनिम्‌॥ ११३॥
तत. सह तया नार्या मद्यपानमथाकरोत्‌। 
सुरापानरत तेन सभार्य तत्यजुस्ततः॥ ११४॥ 
गीतवाद्यादिवनिताभोगससर्गदूषितम्‌।
मन्यमाना महात्मान तया सह बहिष्क्रियम्‌॥ ११५॥


When nevertheless the sons of the Munis did not torsake him, he next
drank intoxicating liquors in company with his wife Thereupon they did
not forsake him, though he was engrossed in drinking spirituous liquor
in company with his wife, and though he was rendered impure by
addiction to singing, musical instruments and such like, and also by
intercourse with his wife; deeming that the high-souled Muni when with
her was detached from religious rites.

The following two slokas identify Dattātreya(दत्तात्रेय) as the lord of yogis [slokas: 116-117]:
नावाप दोषं योगीशो वारुणीं स पिबन्नपि।
अन्तावसायिवेश्मान्तर्मातरिश्वा स्पृशन्निवा  ॥ ११६॥
सुरां पिबन्सपत्नीकस्तपस्तेपे स योगवित्‌।
योगीश्वरश्जिन्त्यमानो यागिभिर्मुक्तिकांक्षिभिः ॥ ११७॥


The lord of yogis, although drinking spirituous liquor, incurred no
fault. Dwelling like Mátarisvan within the abodes of candalas,
drinking strong drink he, skilled in yoga, the lord of yogis, attended
by his wife, performed austerities, being meditated on by yogis who
longed for deliverance from mundane existence.

I) Your first question I read on the website of a Sadhu from Juna Akhara that Dattatreya is the Guru of the Yogis even before Shankara.
It is one hundred percent accurate to express Dattatreya as the Guru of the Yogis [Markandeya purana: Canto-XVII, slokas: 116-117] as described above.
Shankara is believed to belong to Kali Yuga whereas Dattatreya belongs to Tretā Yuga and Who was guru of kārtavīryājunā [refer Canto-XIX] and contemporary to Parasurāma.
II) Your second question Is there any Vedic or Puranic narrative that supports this claim? Who is Dattatreya?.
These details have been covered at the beginning of this answer. Please refer at the top.
III) Your third question What is his connection with Yogi or Sadhus?.
The answer lies in the slokas between 107 and 117 as described above. Please refer them.
IV) Your fourth and final question Why do all sadhus think he is the origin of the Sannyasi Sanghas?
Unlike Rishis, look at his conduct that He carried out Himself unorthodoxly and followed activities similar to Vāmāchāra Mārgam (वामाचार मार्गम्/Left-hand path); particularly, this has attracted Sanniyasi Sanghas and titled him as Guru of the Yogis; refer slokas 116 and 117 as described above that corroborates scripturally these words.
Update:
Sreemad Bhagavatham [Canto-4, Chapter-1, Verse-33] says Dattâtreya as a very powerful yogi (Yoga-vit/योगवित्).
सोमोऽभूद्ब्रह्मणोंऽशेन दत्तो विष्णोस्तु योगवित् ।
दुर्वासा: शङ्करस्यांशो निबोधाङ्गिरस: प्रजा: ॥ ४.१.३३ ॥

Thereafter, from the partial representation of Brahmā, the moon-god
was born of them; from the partial representation of Viṣṇu, the great
mystic [योगवित्/Yoga-vit] Dattātreya was born; and from the partial
representation of Śaṅkara [Lord Śiva], Durvāsā was born.॥ 4.1.33 ॥


Yes, there is a tantra in his name - Dattatreya Tantram. However, the Kumbh thing, I guess there must be some reference.

In fact, I too have a personal copy translated by Pt.Shivadatta Mishra Shastri, published by Krishnadas Acadamy, Varanashi, 1985. However, many readers want to avoid Tantra quotes,  so I go to tantra only as last resort.  Regarding Kumbha, Dattatreya belonged to Treta Yoga like Sri Anjaneya, for whom a seat will be reserved (kept empty) even today in Ramayana upanyasam believing that He will occupy it invisibly. Like Anjaneya, it may be true that Dattatreya visiting every Kumbha!

It is impossible to avoid Tantra or Agama. All the Hindu temple rituals are practised according to Agamas. Unfortunately, ignorant readers are apathetic toward Tantra.

You are right!...

FYI, Sreemad Bhagavatham [Canto-4, Chapter-1, Verse-33] says Dattâtreya as a very powerful yogi (Yoga-vit/योगवित्). I have update the post with this information. https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/4/1/33/
